# Change the matrix values using index vector

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have the following array:

```
AA = zeros(5,3);
AA(1,3)=1;
AA(3,3)=1;
AA(4,2)=1;
```

and I want to place the value one in the collumns defined by the following 
vector `a = [0; 2; 0; 0; 1]`. Each value of this vector refers to the collumn 
index that we want to change in each row. When zero apears no changes should be made.

Desired output:

```
0     0     1
0     1     0
0     0     1
0     1     0
1     0     0
```

Could you please suggest a way to do this without for loop? The goal is
a faster execution.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1

```
nrows = size(AA,1) %// Get the no. of rows, as we would use this parameter later on

%// Calculate the linear indices with `a` as the column indices and 
%// [1:nrows] as the row indices
idx = (a-1)*nrows+[1:nrows]'  %//' 

%// Select the valid linear indices (ones that have the corresponding a as non-zeros
%// and use them to index into AA and set those as 1's
AA(idx(a~=0))=1
```

Code output with given `AA` -

```
>> AA
AA =
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     1     0     0
```

---

### Approach 2

```
AA(sub2ind(size(AA),find(a~=0),a(a~=0)))=1
```

Breaking it down to few steps for explanation:

- `find(a~=0)` and `a(a~=0)` gets us the VALID row and columns indices respectively as needed for `sub2ind(size(),row,column)` format.
- `sub2ind` gets us the linear indices, which we can use to index into input matrix `AA` and set those in `AA` as `1`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive explanations!!